# Managed Metadata and Word 2010 sync issue

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, managed-metadata, term-store, synchronisation, office

We have a document library with a unique content type that contains a managed metadata type column called "Document Type". When bulk documents are uploaded this column is set to a default value called "General". This is done through the *Column Settings UI* under **Term Set Settings** and **Default Value** which take from a specific term store group (no custom workflows or features are involved.)

When users open up the document in Word and make changes/edit it they also need to go in and change the default term in the "Document Type" field to something else, for example, "Accounting:Invoice:Client1" or "HR:Policy:Health Care" etc.

The "Document Type" field is visible and editable in Word 2010. The user can see the selection of terms available from the term store group. The user is able to drill down and select annother term. The user can also make other content changes in the document body and change any other editable properties (Title, Description etc). They can save the document back to the SharePoint library as a new version. No errors occur.

The issue is that the 'Document Type' column in the SharePoint library **never** reflects changes. It always shows "General" as the term however when the document is opened up again, even by another user on another PC, the 'Document Type' field in the document properties reflects the updated term, eg. "Client1".

In short, the terms are being saved to the document itself but do not reflect back to the library 'Document Type' column (our *custom* managed metadata column). Does anyone know what would cause this?

(Environment: Office 2010 (Word) 64-bit, SharePoint 2010 Enterprise, Windows 7 64-bit)

Edit 08/31/2012 : I've clarified a bit based on some feedback.

I'd like to add that the managed metadata column I am having trouble with is a custom column of type "managed metadata". The terms available are subsets of a specific group from the term store as defined in the column's **Term Set Settings** option. This is **not** the column that can be added through the Library settings UI found under **Enterprise Metadata and Keywords Settings**) This Enterprise Metadata column doesn't seem to allow for one subgroup and exposes all terms in the store to all users.